# Rails Actions > Common view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Not sure if i'm taking the right approach here. I've set up various controller actions for variations on a query and for each i've created an associated view/template. All use copies of the same template so it seems counter productive to have individual views......if I decide to change the layout i'd have to change each template.

Here's the actions:

```
def schedule #routes to /products/schedule.html.erb
@products = Product.where('release_date >= ?', Date.today)
end

def active_lines #routes to /products/active_lines.html.erb
@products = Product.where('release_date <= ?', Date.today)
end
```

I'd prefer to have a general products template for these and further actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have several actions displaying list of products, and all have the same "look and feel", you should use a single template. Use [render](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) to specify the template:

```
def schedule
  @products = Product.where('release_date >= ?', Date.today)
  render 'products/list'
end

def active_lines 
  @products = Product.where('release_date <= ?', Date.today)
  render 'products/list'
end
```

Create a single template `products/list.html.erb` instead of the 2 previous templates.

Answer (score 0):

You may like [cell components](http://cells.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this out, but render seems to be what I was after.

Comment: Yeah it's the *raw* way but it's not that testable and reusable way. Anyway, if you were looking for something quick the other answer is good.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on just how simliar your views are you can go with the approach baldrick suggested - or you can setup a nested layout. Have a look at the 
[Rails Guides for Layout and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts)

This will allow you to use your existing application layout with your nested layout rendered inside of that. This allows you to customise each view without reusing a bunch of layout between them.

Comment: Sweet, this sounds useful for some other things I need to do. Loving the rails approach, but taking a while to adjust from PHP.